# Photo folder string replacement Regular Expressions python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I would like to replace

```
text = '2012-02-23 | My Photo Folder'
```

with

```
new_text = '20120223_MyPhotoFolder'
```

I found a regular expression that matches my date format here
http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=933

what is the best way to approach this?
Do I need regular expression groups and then do the replacement in those groups?

I assume I could simply search for " | " and replace with "_ and "-" with "" by normal string.replace(), but I would like to find a more general solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can only give you a "more general solution" if you describe what general cases you would like to cover.

Comment: Let's say I encounter " | " somewhere else in the string. I only want to replace it with "_" if it comes right after the date. Same goes for the "2012-02-23" --> "20120223". I only want to replace "-" --> "" if it occurs within the date part of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

text = '2012-02-23 | My Photo Folder'

pattern = r'''
(?P<year>\d{4}) # year group consisting of 4 digits
-
(?P<month>\d{2}) # month group consisting of 2 digits
-
(?P<date>\d{2}) # date group consisting of 2 digits
\s\|\s
(?P<name_with_spaces>.*$) # name_with_spaces consuming the rest of the string to the end
'''
compiled = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
result = compiled.match(text)
print('{}{}{}_{}'.format(
    result.group('year'),
    result.group('month'),
    result.group('date'),
    result.group('name_with_spaces').translate(None,' ')))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
20120223_MyPhotoFolder
```

---

#### A little explanation:

[`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) lets us write regular expression in multiple lines making it more readable and also allows comments.

[`'{}{}{}_{}'.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) is just a string interpolation method which puts arguments in the places specified by `{}`.

[`translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) method is applied to `result.group('name_with_spaces')` to remove spaces.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!
I was just gonna ask about this.
That does exactly what I need to do. The only thing I added was an if statement checking whether result is true or false, since there list of directories might have things that I don't want to touch.